# viewmodel and view control order of execution

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependencies

I have a serious problem with the order of execution in MVVM:
this code instaceiate the view (XAML):

```
<local:ExecutionView x:Name="ExecutionView" DataContext="{Binding ExecutionViewNodel}"/>
```

`ExecutionView`  has inner field of viewmodel (`_viewModel = DataContext as ExecutionViewModel;`).
In its CTOR it uses the viewmodel- `_viewModel.DoSomthing();`

problem is that it is null..

I cant control the timing of the binding- i have read a bit and there ways of handling the issue with (Loaded event and datacontextchanged)- still i think it is a workaround and NOT the way it should be done.

i need a way to control the steps where i can write a function that will be called once after the DataContext is certain to be valid.

BR, Mosh.

Comment: `I have a serious problem` - yes, you should begin accept the answers, at least sometimes.

Comment: your right my bad- actually forgot to accept two answers i have asked prev, any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `DataContext` in your constructor, when it isn't quite available yet, subscribe to the `DataContextChanged` event in the constructor, and when your even handler is called, grab the reference to the new `DataContext` and perform whatever operations you need.

It's also possible to declare an event handler in your XAML, so the subscription to the event doesn't need to be in the constructor.

[Here is a link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) regarding that event.

Comment: this i know of, thanks, isnt there a more orderd way of syncing the xaml to the code behind?

Comment: I guess a better question you might ask yourself is "Why do I need to access the DataContext from the constructor (or elsewhere in code behind) anyway?" Very, very rarely have I ever needed to do this myself. And if you're looking for a better way to synchronize with a changing DataContext, DataContextChanged is a very good answer, as that's the *whole point* of that event.